# How can we enforce custom password complexity in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Is there any way to enforce password policy for Cassandra database users? Something like the password must contains 8 characters with a special character , an upper case character and a lower case.

FYI, we are on Datastax Cassandra latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define a password complexity policy when using the internal Cassandra authenticator (`PasswordAuthenticator`).

If you have a policy that requires the use of complex passwords, you will need to authenticate against an external third-party system such as Active Directory where you can create policies that would enforce password complexity. Then configure your cluster to use an LDAP authenticator.

For [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) clusters, the Advanced Security features allow you [to define an authentication scheme with LDAP](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.8/security/secDSEUnifiedAuthAbout.html) as a backend. DSE passes the credentials for verification against an LDAP server.

For open-source Apache Cassandra clusters, you can install [Instaclustr's LDAP plugin](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-ldap) to authenticate against an LDAP server.